# I need to transform the output of the jq comand into a table

Tags: json, jq

I am using this command to extract some information from a Json.

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN=$(oc whoami -t)
ENDPOINT=$(oc config current-context | cut -d/ -f2 | tr - .)
NAMESPACE=$(oc config current-context | cut -d/ -f1)


curl -k \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    https://$ENDPOINT/api/v1/resourcequotas |   jq -jr '[[.items[].metadata.namespace ], [.items[].metadata.creationTimestamp ], [.items[].spec.hard["requests.storage"]],[.items[].status.used["requests.storage"]],[.items[].spec.hard["limits.cpu"]],[.items[].spec.hard["limits.memory"]],[.items[].status.used["limits.cpu"]],[.items[].status.used["limits.memory"]]] ' > item.txt
```

When i execute the script it return an txt file with this:

```
[
  [
    "glusterfs",
    "timpdv",
    "timpdv",
    "whatsappprd",
    "whatsappprd",
    "wso2ms",
    "wso2ms"
  ],
  [
    "2019-12-12T13:47:25Z",
    "2019-01-10T19:53:29Z",
    "2019-01-10T20:36:18Z",
    "2019-02-15T17:39:43Z",
    "2019-02-13T18:20:30Z",
    "2019-12-12T13:49:57Z",
    "2019-12-12T13:50:45Z"
  ],
  [
    "200Gi",
    null,
    "300Gi",
    null,
    "1150Gi",
    null,
    "200Gi"
  ],
  [
    "0",
    null,
    "68Gi",
    null,
    "1074Gi",
    null,
    "0"
  ],
  [
    null,
    "16",
    null,
    "192",
    null,
    "80",
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    "192Gi",
```

And I need to return this data as a table, each value is a column.
Ex.

```
namespace,        timestamp,              request.storage
 "glusterfs",    "2019-12-12T13:47:25Z",    "200Gi",
    "timpdv",    "2019-01-10T19:53:29Z",    null,
    "timpdv",    "2019-01-10T20:36:18Z",    "300Gi",
```

Comment: In bash!? You're a sadist.

Comment: I am not a sadist rs, i just need it done rsrs.
I am extracting this information from prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the header line, it looks like the jq query you want is more like this:

```
.items[]
| [.metadata.namespace,
   .metadata.creationTimestamp,
   .spec.hard["requests.storage"],
   .status.used["requests.storage"],
   .spec.hard["limits.cpu"],
   .spec.hard["limits.memory"],
   .status.used["limits.cpu"],
   .status.used["limits.memory"]]
| @tsv
```

For CSV, use `@csv` instead of `@tsv`. In either case, you will probably want to invoke jq with the -r option.

Comment: It almost this , the only thing i didn't understand is why everithing has a 't'
"glusterfs\t2019-12-12T13:47:25Z\t200Gi\t0\t\t\t\t"

Comment: `\t` is the JSON representation of a tab. Please see update.

Comment: Right, now make sense . Thank you , i almost quit using jq